# Python Pyramid: image upload giving request.DisconnectionError

Tags: python, api, file-upload, pyramid

I am writing a code to upload image using Python Pyramid framework.

This is the sample code I have written:

```
from pyramid.view import view_config
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.response import Response

@view_config(route_name="hello", renderer="json", request_method="POST")
def hello(request):
    print(request.params) # this line is giving an error when I upload an image
    return Response('Hello World!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = Configurator()
    config.add_route("hello")
    config.scan()
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()

    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 6544, app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Running this API from postman. I wanted to get all input params in `request.params`. If I am selecting Text input, I am getting correct output.

[image]

**But, if I am attaching an image (selecting file image in above picture), it is giving following error.**

```
print(request.params)
*** webob.request.DisconnectionError: The client disconnected while sending the body (5326 more bytes were expected)
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Did you include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the request?

Comment: @StevePiercy: while calling from postman, I am selecting form-data. (As shown in picture in a question)

Comment: Please include the actual request. An image of a UI is not the request. Postman has a feature to display the request as a `curl` object and other options.